# XamarinMediaManager: Cover album (album artwork) is not displayed in the look-screen or control center

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my code that works very well. It makes me visualize in the control center (look-screen) of the device:

- the title
- the artist
- the album

It does not make me visualize the cover image. Why ? Do you have a solution? This problem is only with stream url and not with mp3 file.

```
public async Task PlayStreamingClassic()
{
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://dreamsiteradiocp3.com/proxy/radiocharlie? 
    mp=/stream");
}

public async Task LeggiMetaData()
{
    var httpClient1 = new HttpClient();
    var ArtistTitle = await httpClient1.GetStringAsync("https://example.com/ArtistTitle.txt");
    var Artist = ArtistTitle.Substring(0, ArtistTitle.IndexOf('-'))?.Trim();
    var Title = ArtistTitle.Substring(ArtistTitle.IndexOf('-') + 1)?.Trim();

    var httpClient2 = new HttpClient();
    var CoverAlbum = await httpClient2.GetStringAsync("https://example.com/CoverAlbum.txt");

    lblArtistTitle.Text = ArtistTitle;
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.IsMetadataExtracted = false;
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Title = Title;
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Artist = Artist;
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Album = "Radio Charlie Classic";
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.DisplayImage = "https://example.com/" + CoverAlbum + ".jpg";
    CrossMediaManager.Current.Notification.UpdateNotification();
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to achieve the result like following sceenshot?

[image]

[image]

Here is my Play code.`AlbumImageUri` should be `https`, you can use my url to make a test

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3");
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.IsMetadataExtracted = false;
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Title="test";
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.AlbumImageUri= "https://secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/event/4/7/b/8/600_455178360.jpeg";
        }
```

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the left upper corner), it will help others who have similar issue.